# How to call a UIViewController from a UIView SubClass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have main `UIViewController` in which I have an `UITableView`.

In the cell of `UItableView` I had already add an `UICollectionView`.

in -

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am calling an method of main `UIViewController`.

```
UIViewController *view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[view my_method];
```

in main view.

```
-(void)my_method {
    AnotherName *view_my=[[AnotherName alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnotherName" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view_my animated:NO];
}
```

`Viewdidload` method is calling but `view` is not showing.

Comment: read about adding childViewControllers. you need to understand object oriented concepts here. simply making a new instance of view wont effect current heirarchy

Comment: see your View_my method code ?

Comment: When you select an item in the collection view, can you specify what you then want the app to do. That way I can show you how its done. Because however you are doing it doesn't seem clear from what you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution..

```
AnotherName *view_my = [[AnotherName alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnotherName" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = view_my;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Spacial thanks to `@The Mech System` .. To help me out find the solution ..
now it is working fine.

Comment: I'm glad that it helps. Could you please mark my answer accepted if it helped you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you initialise by calling `[[UIViewController alloc] init]`. This always returns empty view.

You should instead call this

- If you use storyboard give the view controller a storyboard id and call this

`MainViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard id"];`

- If you use interface builder, call this

`MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nib File Name" bundle:nil];`

Comment: i am trying this but it is not navigating to view.  I put breakpoints, viewdidload method is called but view is not showing .

Comment: Why would you name it UIViewController? You cannot name it UIViewController as it will call the Apple default UIViewController not your custom UIViewController.

Comment: I want to call another view controller from a uiview class .

Comment: What I mean is change this name : AnotherName *view_my=[[AnotherName alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnotherName" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view_my animated:NO];

Comment: it's call viewdidload but not showing the view on screen .

Comment: Did you rename the "UIViewController.h" and "UIViewController.m" to "AnotherName.h" and "AnotherName.m" as well? Also, make sure the "UIViewController.xib" is also rename correctly to "AnotherName.xib".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115361/discussion-between-abhishek-mishra-and-the-mach-system).